# CPython WPF interop

Tags: wpf, interop, cpython

Is this possible?

Is there any thinkable way to have interop between a CPython scripting app (3rd party) and a WPF UI app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are plenty of ways.  Both CPython and .NET support quite a few forms of [IPC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365574%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), which could easily be used to allow them to communicate.